# ansible-playbook wait for ssh timing out with ping error, but works locally

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to ssh to an ec2 instance, via my ansible-playbook file.  I can ssh into the instance locally, and currently have the following configuration in my ansible-playbook file:

```
- name: Wait for SSH to come up
  delegate_to: "{{ public_dns }}"
  wait_for_connection:
    delay: 60
    timeout: 120
  with_items: "{{ public_ip }}"
  remote_user: ubuntu
  connection: ssh
  register: item
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

> failed: [localhost -> {{ public_dns }}] (item={'_ansible_item_result':
>   True, '_ansible_no_log': False, '_ansible_delegated_vars':
>   {'ansible_delegated_host': u'{{ public_dns }}', 'ansible_host': u'{{
>   public_dns }}'}, 'changed': False, 'elapsed': 184, 'failed': True,
>   'item': u'{{ public_ip }}', 'msg': u"timed out waiting for ping module
>   test success: 'ping'", '_ansible_ignore_errors': None}) => {"changed":
>   false, "elapsed": 184, "item": "{{ public_ip }}", "msg": "timed out
>   waiting for ping module test success: 'ping'"}

When I ping the public_dns or public_ip value from my machine both are successful.

Why would the ping event fail when running the Ansible file?  (I'm not purposefully trying to ping the instance, I actually want to connect to it via ssh.  However the error shows that Ansible may be trying to ping the instance before connecting, based on the "timed out waiting for ping module test success")

I have since changed the method to:

```
- name: Add new instance to host group
  add_host:
  hostname: ""{{ public_ip }}"
  groupname: launched

- name: Wait for SSH to come up
  wait_for:
    host: launched
    port: 22
    sleep: 30
    delay: 10
    timeout: 360
  state: started
```

However, this has been throwing a different error, of "Timeout when waiting for launched:22" The traceback includes the following:

> connect_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), connect_timeout)  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
>       for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):.

Any ideas?

Comment: there is two `"` in `hostname: ""{{ public_ip }}"` but I think it's just a wrong copy paste in stackoverflow

Comment: Just to note for future users, this might be a symptom of ssh connection failing, and on OS X this can be caused by sshpass program not being available.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that Ansible **ping module** is not the same as **ICMP Ping**: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/ping_module.html. Ansible will try to connect to the target host via `ssh` when using the ping module

If the above task is inside a playbook that is run against a newly provisioned ec2 instance, I would set `gather_facts: false` and run the `wait_for_connection` as my first task. If it still fails, try increasing the `timeout` parameter

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've tried both the gather_facts and moving the wait_for_connection task, however this is still failing, I think that it may not be correctly using the sshkey? - any advice on this?

Comment: I think the error message would say something about authentication if you're using the wrong sshkey. Have you tried increasing the `timeout` parameter?

Comment: Yes I have increased it to 600 seconds, and this is well after I can ssh into the machine outside of the ansible script.

Comment: Just saw your updated code and I agree that it's cleaner and simpler now. Quick comment: shouldn't `host: launched` point to the actual host `{{ public_up }}` instead of the group?